# Response time when using select with Eloquent

Tags: eloquent

I have the following query, and it's taking about 4 minutes to run. How can I improve this just by changing the query, since it's impossible for me to alter the database, please.

```
$results = ReportsItems::selectRaw("
            device_name AS column_0,
            COUNT(DISTINCT reports_items.order_guid) as column_1,
            FLOOR(AVG(CASE WHEN reports.is_expo = 1 THEN reports_items_bump.done_time_seconds ELSE reports_items_bump.prep_time_seconds END)) as column_2
        ")
        ->join('reports', 'reports.order_guid', '=', 'reports_items.order_guid')
        ->join('reports_items_bump', 'reports_items.item_bump_guid', '=', 'reports_items_bump.item_bump_guid')
        ->whereIn('reports_items.order_guid', function ($query) use ($storeGuid, $dateBegin, $dateEnd) {
            $query->select('order_guid')
                ->from('reports')
                ->where('store_guid', $storeGuid)
                ->whereBetween('timestamp', [$dateBegin, $dateEnd]);
        })
        ->whereIn('reports_items_bump.item_bump_guid', function ($query) {
            $query->select('item_bump_guid')
                ->from('reports_items_bump')
                ->where('prep_time_seconds', '>', 0)
                ->orWhere('done_time_seconds', '>', 0);
        })
        ->groupBy('device_name')
        ->get();

        return $results;
```